# Minimum sum from a dictionary of lists in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm newish to Python (and stackoverflow)...bear with me!  I have a dictionary that looks like this:

`valueDict[i] = [x,y]`

I want to find the minimum key based on the sum of x and y. I know for a dictionary of values I can use:

`minVal = min(valueDict, key=valueDict.get)`

But I don't think I can modify this approach for a dict of lists.

Comment: Please format your code, and make sure the example you give is correct -- `min(dict, key=dict.get())` is wrong. Also, `dict.get` is ambiguous -- it appears you're referring to the `get` method of `dict` instance you also named `dict`, but it could also mean the unbound `get` method of the `dict` class. That's why you shouldn't use common built-ins as variable names even in examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can provide any function for the `key` argument of `min`. For a dictionary of values you do

```
minVal = min(dict, key=dict.get) # note no parentheses
```

If you wanted to the minimum based on the sum, you might do

```
minVal = min(dict, key=lambda i: sum(dict[i]))
```

Comment: Or, to avoid a hash lookup for every item, `min(dict.iteritems(), key = lambda k, v: sum(v))[1]`

Comment: @agf Are we expecting a non-trivial improvement in speed in certain cases by avoiding the hash lookup? I think hash lookups in dictionaries are already `O(1)`

Comment: @gameveloster A hash lookup can actually be quite expensive compared to other operations, but you're right we're talking about constant factor improvements here. It's unlikely to be worth the reduced readability in real world cases. Keep in mind this is over a decade old :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
minVal = min(d, key=lambda x: sum(d[x]))
```

where d is the dict.